# DelphiXE7: Where''s the WinAPI help topics?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe7

Hello I just finally buy the newest Delphi after many years using older version or free pascal. Everything seem to work as expected except when I look the help I can't find winapi or opengl topics like i could in old version.

Do I need to install something special so I can press f1 over for example "messagebox" or "sleep" or "glcolor" or whatever because I install delphi xe7 3 times now but there is only "Install Help" option during install and no other help option I can see.

Comment: I can't understand why you are asking this question here. You haven't even Googled your problem, and I can't see why you thought reinstalling it 3 times would solve your trouble.

Comment: I tried to ask google about all I could think for "Delphi XE7 missing winapi topics in help file" or similar is no find any useful thing at all. For reinstalling i figure maybe there was an option i didn't see. For asking here it's because i don't know where else to ask and many people know a lot so I though it ok to ask.

Comment: Try asking in the [Embarcadero forums](http://forums.embaracadero.com) (there is a [recent question](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=111558) on this same topic), or contact [Embarcadero Support](http://support.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Type the name of the function into google and read the docs on msdn

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I had tried to fix this annoying change from how it was to limited success. What I had done was:
- install the documentation part of "Windows 7 SDK with .net 3.5" (won't work with any later SDK installs since they changed help format)
- install a program from helpware called FAR
- in program FAR, choose H2 UTILS, then select "embarcadero.rs_xe7", then click register
- go to plugins and add WIN7SDKCOM

That was it, with that done both the table of contents and index of delphi help contained the whole windows 7 documentation. HOWEVER! There was a problem, and it was that many (most?) winapi F1 context sensitive help didn't work, it still took me to the standard delphi help page that said to go to MSDN even though if i went to the index i would immediately find the topic.

So, imperfect answer that I'm relaying from memory since I reinstalled that computer and didn't add the win7sdk this time. Hopefully it helps, I know I was happy to have easier offline access to the documentation. Maybe someone can figure out the extra step to make F1 help also work completely.